# How to filter a column in excel based on a condition of sequence in cell contents?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to filter set of rows in an excel, where filter column should follow a sequence in a column i.e., 1 > 2 > 3. Can anyone guide me for the same.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Value 2 |
| Cell 2 | Value 3 |
| Cell 3 | Value 4 |
| Cell 1 | Value 2 |
| Cell 2 | Value 3 |
| Cell 3 | Value 4 |
| Cell 1 | Value 5 |
| Cell 1 | Value 6 |
| Cell 2 | Value 7 |
| Cell 1 | Value 8 |

should be filtered as

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Value 2 |
| Cell 2 | Value 3 |
| Cell 3 | Value 4 |
| Cell 1 | Value 2 |
| Cell 2 | Value 3 |
| Cell 3 | Value 4 |

Tried advanced filters but could not find way to define more than 2 conditions

Comment: Why don't you filter cell 1 and 2 with values 6 and 7?  Does it need to be a sequence of at least 3 numbers or do you only want to filter the sequence 2, 3, 4? A bit more guidance would help

Comment: How many diferent types of sequences are you dealing with? always "cell 1-3" or could it be alphabetical orering, or "one, two, three" or "1", "10", "11", or name of Popes in chronoligal order (I could think of a zillion different exampes - and - given time - I'd surely approach infinity!"  - ok,ok, so let's assume sequential numbers with unit increment (so not just odd number sequences, or Fibonacci sequence, or primes etc....."  I'll have a think about this - fyi - the "related questions" that are shown below ae bizarre - hardly relate to the topic of your question let alone nuances..

Comment: @karl - ues I would argue same - well spotted - assuming this was oversight/missed on the part of OP..

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9htQxz_ew40ALSYoQXg?e=pY3WLs)/screenshots refer:

To create binary filter denoting 'is sequence' y/n resp. that appears to work*♣*, two helper cols can be used as follows:

**h_1:**

```
=IFERROR(D1:D11-D2:D12,-D2:D12)
```

[image: h_1]

**h_2:**

```
=LET(x_,D3:D13-D2:D12,x1_,INDEX(x_,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x_),1,ROWS(x_),-1)),--x1_)
```

[image: h_2]

**Filter**

The filter is then constructed using:

```
=LET(a0_,--(COUNTIFS(B2#,B2#)>1),a_,SORTBY(a0_,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a0_)),-1),b_,--(COUNTIFS(A2#,A2#)>1),IF(a_+b_>1,1,a_+b_))
```

[image: filter]

---

**Notes**

- requires Office 365 compatible vers. Excel
- Key feature: sequence can be defined as any arithmetic sequence with constant increment/decrement (multiple sequences with different inc/decrement can also be handled - per screenshot)

---

**Caveats/limitations:**

*♣* *limited testing - certain combinations e.g. 2,-1,3,0,4, etc. where altrnating sequence exists (every 2nd element) may trigger filter =1 (user-testing advisable, especially for long data cols)*

- dependencies: two helper functions could not be avoided in viable manner due to limitations associated with countifs() function that is used to spill arrays
- in particular, functions within criteria/count range are not handled well/robust fasion (albeit countifs, I believe, handles references to better extent than sumifs etc.) - all the same, compressing into single function would impede tractability / auditability
- A more robust validation tehcnique for this kkind of teset

---

Comment: What's the ♣ mean?

Comment: It's a reference from the first line of the solution to the notes below (was that the only Q you had RE: this soln?) Ahh - thought you were the OP - nevermind